# the better way to change TTB_BASE?

Tags: arm

turning off/on mmu is not a good way to switch TTB_BASE in ARM as far as I know .So what is the better way ?
Is the main steps like this ? (ARM 920T ARMV4T)

> 1 . sync dcache --> external memory 
>   2 . clean_icache () && invalidate_dcache () ; // this is my question ,if the current instruction alreay in  icache ,then I clean  & invalidate them ,how can ARM core knows what is the next step ? May ARM core fetch instructions from external memory again ? 
>   3. invalidate whole tlb 
>   4.  change the ttb base register

Is there another better way ? Any help appreciated ! ^_^

Comment: ARM memory management has evolved quite a bit through the progression of the architecture. Please provide information about what processor or architecture version you are targeting.

Comment: ARM920T arm core ARMV4T arch .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Switching the `TTB_BASE` is much the same as turning on the MMU.  Before the operation, there is one memory space and after there is another.  You need your currently executing code to remain valid during the operation.  Choices are,

1. Map current code to same location in both.
2. Rely on a cache to transition.

The 1<sup>st</sup> is basically with *phys* `==` *virt* when enabling the MMU.  When updating the `TTB_BASE` a complete copy of the old version is the most basic.  If interrupts are locked, you may only need to map pages needed by the *switching code*.  This maybe a two phase operation where the current code page is eventually re-located to some other memory address.  First *alias* the page, *branch* to the *alias* location and remove the *original* page.  At every step, it is safe to flush the *TLB* and caches.  You may not need to do this, depending on the context of the change.  However, after the first *flush*, sub-sequent flushes are not expensive for each of *d-cache*, *i-cache* and *TLB*.

The 2<sup>nd</sup> method is rather flakey.  On the **StrongARM**, this was known as the *dance of death*, when enabling the MMU.  Basically, the instructions where timed so that prefetching and *NOP* padding would sequence the instructions so that a *branch* was performed from the *phys* address to the *virt* address right at the time of transition.  For updating the `TTB_BASE`, you can assume that the current code page is in the TLB and if the code is *aligned* properly it starts an *I-CACHE* line.  There are about six instructions that maybe performed after the `TTB_BASE` update before any memory will be fetched by the CPU.  It is a full page, if you don't flush the *TLB*.

I can only see the 2<sup>nd</sup> method being used in the case of a *hypervisor* that wants to switch an entire memory map frequently; generally *hypervisors* will only change part of the *memory map* on a *context switch*.  The 2<sup>nd</sup> method is slightly faster, but the down sides should be obvious.

Comment: Thanks a lot,The 1st way seems to be safer .It's what I need.. 
Thanks ...^_^