# Why fill “0x50C06” to level 1 page table entry?

Tags: assembly, arm, mmu, cortex-a

Why fill the table entry with value `0x50C06` in the follow code?

```
    TTB_ENTRY_SUPERSEC_DEV  DEFINE   0x50C06 
                                           ; Setup page table.
    LDR     r0,=SFE(MMU_TT)                     ; Load page table base address


                                                ; Init the whole page table as dev memory by default
    MOV     r4, #0x00000000
    MOV     r3, r0
    ADD     r3, r3, #0x0

TTbl_Dev_Loop1
    MOV32   r1, #TTB_ENTRY_SUPERSEC_DEV
    ADD     r1, r1, r4
    MOV     r5, #16
TTbl_Dev_Loop2
    STR     r1, [r3], #4
    SUBS    r5, r5, #1
    BNE     TTbl_Dev_Loop2
    ADD     r4, r4, #0x1000000
    CMP     r4, #0x0
    BNE     TTbl_Dev_Loop1
```

Comment: `SFE` is an IAR assembler psuedo-op which give the base of a linker section; so MMU_TT must be a linker address and this code is for the IAR ARM assembler.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [first level ARM page table](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.ddi0333h/ch06s11s02.html) has **sections** and **super sections**.

```
Bits    |31   24|  20|19|18|17|16| 15|14 12|11 10|9|8    5| 4|3|2|1|0
--------+------------+--+--+--+--+---+-----+-----+-+------+--+-+-+-+-
Section |Base address|NS| 0|nG| s|APX|  TEX|   AP|P|Domain|XN|C|B|1|0
Super   |Base   | SBZ|NS| 1|nG| s|APX|  TEX|   AP|P|Ignore|XN|C|B|1|0
0x50C06 |            | 0| 1| 0| 1|0  |  000|   11|0|  0000| 0|0|1|1|0
is super|            |  | *|...
```

These allow mapping a large portion of memory 16MB at a time.  Each first level table entry represents 1MB of address space.  Super sections repeats this 16 times for a total of 16MB.  This is the code,

```
    MOV     r5, #16         ; 16 entries.
TTbl_Dev_Loop2
    STR     r1, [r3], #4    ; write entry
    SUBS    r5, r5, #1      ; decrement and test for zero.
    BNE     TTbl_Dev_Loop2  ; branch if more needed.
```

The rest of the code just changes the base with the `r4` register. `ADD r4, r4, #0x1000000` is stepping 16MB through the address space.  So this maps all virtual addresses to the physical addresses.  This is often used during booting a system, when the MMU is first turned on and cache can be enabled.  Typical devices don't have 4GB of actual physical memory (and peripherals), so the unused physical addresses can be re-used by updating the table.  It is also possible to [change the *super sections*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16383007/what-is-the-right-way-to-update-mmu-translation-table) to have page table entries (l2 page tables with [4-64Kb sizes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37511323/why-does-arm-have-64kb-large-pages)) as the system is running.

It also seems that all the memory is set to device memory (at least to start) so that no type of caching will be used.  Some of these other bits (AP,TEX,etc) depend on CP15 register values which are not shown.

See also: [ARMv7 One-to-One mapping](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33328556/in-context-of-armv7-what-is-the-advantage-of-linux-kernel-one-to-one-mapped-memo)
                [Change TTB_BASE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16434986/the-better-way-to-change-ttb-base)
                [ARM Paging](https://wiki.osdev.org/ARM_Paging)

Comment: Your boot code (or whatever this is) may run substantially faster if you enable cache. Typically 2 to 10 times speed up depending on circumstances. Of course cache can cause issue, but it is usually due to some poor programming where an error may occur anyway, but less frequently.

Comment: Thanks！This problem has been bothering me for a long time, because I don't know where to find the relevant information from the manual.。

Comment: Yes, they are **reference** manuals and not tutorials for learning so the information is all over the place.